# What is the simplest way to inject a function into an angularjs module?

Tags: angularjs

I currently have 3 angularjs modules, each of which are (roughly) like so:

```
(function () {
    var generalApp = angular.module('general-app', []);    
    generalApp.controller("NewsletterSignup.Controller", ["$scope", "$http", NewsletterSignupControllerFunction]); 
}());
```

where `NewsletterSignupControllerFunction` is a global variable that is a reference to a function, eg:

`var NewsletterSignupControllerFunction = function ($scope, $http) { ... };`

Rather than use a global variable to share logic between the three modules, what is the simplest way to inject `NewsletterSignupControllerFunction` into each of the modules so I can use it to create the controllers? I have tried various approaches, none of which I can get to work.

Comment: create a module wich holds your function as a service, use this module as dependency for your other modules.

Comment: why u can not just defined controller in common module?

Comment: Try keeping the function in a separate js file and exporting it. Now, import the function in files wherever required and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to define a common module with the controller:

### common.js

```
(function () {
     angular.module('common', [])   
     .controller("NewsletterSignup.Controller",
        ["$scope", "$http", NewsletterSignupControllerFunction]
     )

     function NewsletterSignupControllerFunction ($scope,$http) {
         //code ...
     }   
}());
```

Use that common module as a dependency:

```
angular.module("myApp",['common'])
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)